# GML structure and SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, export

I need to convert entire SQL Server view(s) into *GML* file. I partly succeed, but there is maybe some simpler way (my way is not simple definitely).
I have this at the moment:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www._.com' AS fgu, 'http://www.opengis.net/gml' as gml)
SELECT *
FROM [vParcela] as [fgu:attName]
FOR XML PATH('fgu:Parcela'), ROOT('gml:featureMember')
```

and getting something like:

```
<gml:featureMember xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:fgu="www._.com">
  <fgu:Parcela>
    <lwr>6437356.24 4949868.47</lwr>
    <upp>6437368.53 4949878.06</upp>
    <oid>6158487618342</oid>
    <lineage_Parent>6158487458742</lineage_Parent>
```

I need to get prefix tags for every view's column (e.g. `fgu:lwr, fgu:upp` ...).

Is there a way to do this with `select *` and not defining all column names? And, againg, is there other way to export entire view(s) into one gml file at once (create single *GML* file from DB with complete gml structure)?

**EDIT:** Without software like *FME*, or other commercial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It [seems the only EASY way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) is to use columns names `SELECT lwr as [fgu:lwr], ...`.

Also you can try to use `REPLACE()` to do it:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('www._.com' AS fgu, 'http://www.opengis.net/gml' as gml)
SELECT 
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(
    REPLACE(      
(SELECT *
     FROM [vParcela] as [fgu:attName]
     FOR XML PATH('Parcela'),ROOT('featureMember')
 ) 
    ,'</','</fgu:')  
    ,'<','<fgu:')
    ,'<fgu:/','</')
    ,'<fgu:featureMember','<gml:featureMember')
    ,'</fgu:featureMember','</gml:featureMember')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/584ca9/2)</kbd>

Comment: It is partly good, but I have geometry fields in my view, so it's attributes need to be gml, not fgu. But this is what I supposed I must do, using replaces. I thought it may be of use other versions of FOR XML to make things easy. :/

Comment: P.S. I visited first link, but SQDLFiddle is good one :) Thanks